# Integrability of second derivative of infinity harmonic functions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the infinity harmonic functions, i.e. solutions of the equation

$$
\Delta_\infty u = \langle Du, D^2 u \, Du \rangle = 0.
$$

It is known that the solutions are everywhere differentiable (continuous differentiability is an open question), and in the plane it is known that the solutions are $C^{1,\alpha}$.

My question is: Is anything known about the second derivative of the solutions, or even its trace, the laplacian? Do we have, for example, that $D^2u \in L^1$, or even Radon measure? Or do we have that $\Delta u$ is a Radon measure?

These properties do hold for the Aronsson solution
$$u(x,y) = x^{4/3}-y^{4/3}$$
which is taken as the archetypal solution to infinity Laplace equation.

(I asked the question earlier on Mathoverflow, https://mathoverflow.net/q/162046/1445, and got no attention whatsoever.)

Comment: For really technical questions like this, if you don't get an answer on MO, you _probably_ won't get one here either. Off the top of my head, I don't see any reason why the Laplacian (which is no longer connected to the structure of your operator) should exhibit any cancellations that makes it behave obviously better than the Hessian.

Comment: What do you mean by $D^2u$? The aronssons exaple is not twice diferentiable at the origin.